# Processing a 'POST' or 'GET' for a path in Struts application

Tags: java, post, get, struts-1

I am through a struts application, trying to understand the flow and architecture, I come across the below logs while running the application,

```
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor 2016-06-07 11:33:36,553 -- DEBUG -- Processing a 'POST' for path '/xyz'
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor 2016-06-07 11:33:37,553 -- DEBUG -- 
Processing a 'GET' for path '/abc'?
```

the path '/xyz' or '/abc' is not configured for GET or POST , I am unable to understand where the configurations are made, or is it an internal behavior ?

Since the application is vast I am unsure if I have provided enough information for my query.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know these paths(Actions) in Struts accept both GET/POST requests.It must be the default internal behavior.But if you want to define paths(Actions) for GET or POST requests separately , you can use **request.getMethod()** and define the logic.